# How to replace an invokable class in the RoutePluginManager in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-route

I've written a custom `Part` class (`MyNamespace\Mvc\Router\Http\Part`), that shall now be used instead instead of the `Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Part`. How to load it to the list of the invokables of the [`Zend\Mvc\Router\RoutePluginManager`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/RoutePluginManager.php)?

[image]

--

EDIT:

Just tried it with

```
namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module {
    ...
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $mvcEvent) {
        ...
        $routePluginManager = $mvcEvent->getRouter()->getRoutePluginManager();
        $routePluginManager->setInvokableClass('part', 'MyWorkspace\Mvc\Router\Http\Part');
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

but it's not working -- the standard Zend class is still used.

Answer (score 1):

Either have your Module class implement the `Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\RouteProviderInterface` and declare the `getRouteConfig` method it requires

```
<?php
namespace Application;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature;

class Module implements Feature\RouteProviderInterface
{

    public function getRouteConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'invokables' => array(
                 'part' => 'ITT\Mvc\Router\Http\Part',
            ),
        );
    }

 }
```

Or, add it to your `module.config.php` file under the `route_manager` key

```
 return array(

     'route_manager' => array(
         'invokables' => array(
             'part' => 'ITT\Mvc\Router\Http\Part',
          ),
      ),

  );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Neither the variant with the `getRouteConfig()`, nor the one with the `module.config.php` is working for me. The class is loaded in to the `PoutePluginManager`, but then the `Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Part#match(...)` called instead of `MyNamespace\Mvc\Router\Http\Part#match(...)`.

Comment: A took a look into the [`Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack#init()`](https://github.com/weierophinney/Component_ZendMvc/blob/master/Router/Http/TreeRouteStack.php#L43). It's the place, where the route plugin manager gets its invokables. Both classes are loaded -- as the Zend one as well mine. They have different canonical names (`RoutePluginManager#canonicalNames`). My suspicion is, that my custom class is "ignored", because the object, that calls the `Path#match(...)` searchs in the list of invokables by canonical name `zendmvcrouterhttppart`.

Comment: The instantiating if the `Part` class takes place in the `Zend\Mvc[\Router\RoutePluginManager#setInvokableClass(...)`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/RoutePluginManager.php#L43). It gets the canonical name "part" and looks up in the invokables array. And my custoom class is not there. I use another custom class, that works (a custom route `MyNamespace\Mvc\Router\Http\UnicodeRegex`), but it's also not there. There are no custom classes there at all. The value of the "part" is the Zend `Part` class and it is instantited.

Comment: OK, I found out, what the problem is: The [`Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack#init()`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Http/TreeRouteStack.php#L79) overrides the route config. It iterates an internal array and calls the `RoutePluginManager#setInvokableClass(...)` with the arguments: `$name` = the canonical name (in our case "part") and `$class` = `__NAMESPACE__ . '\ClassName'` (in our case `__NAMESPACE__ . '\Part'`). `__NAMESPACE__` is `Zend\Mvc\Router\Http` -- also the invokable class is `Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Part`. Is it a bug? How to resolve it?

Comment: Probably little late to the party. Well I had the same "issue" but thanks to above I knew where to look. Lucky me I got more "issues" with zf2 so I made my own fork. In the `init` of `TreeRouteStack` where `setInvokableClass` is called, I placed an `if` around it with `!$routes->has($name)`. And now it works